# MongoDB $size is not allowed in this atlas tier, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to return this only if there are 2 `by` in the data array. The number of `_id` can be unlimited.

However, the code `{ $size: { data: 2 }, }` does not work because I get **$size is not allowed in this atlas tier** error.

Expected return:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Something1?",
        "data": [
            {
                "by": "user1",
            },
            {
                "by": "user2",
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to include something like `$size` in the code, otherwise it will return the data even if there is only 1 `by`, or 3 `by`, or 0 `by`. I only want to return the data if there are 2 `by`.

What should I do? Full code without $size:

```
let x = await Answer.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            by: {
                                $in: [user.email, user2[0].email],
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$question",
                    data: {
                        $push: "$$ROOT",
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    "data._id": 0,
                    "data.question": 0,
                    "data.__v": 0,
                },
            },
            { $sort: { "data.date": -1 } },
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your atlas tier doesn't support `$size`.

But you can have a field like `count` that increments by 1 when grouping:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$question",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
        
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: 2
    }
  }
])
```

Try this in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qPP0o5lOGUz)

**Update**

Finally, your aggregation should look like this:

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    by: {
                        $in: [user.email, user2[0].email],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$question",
            data: {
                $push: "$$ROOT",
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: 2
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "data._id": 0,
            "data.question": 0,
            "data.__v": 0,
            "count": 0
        },
    },
    { $sort: { "data.date": -1 } },
]
```

You can learn more about `$sum` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html).

Comment: And I can't do it like return if there are 2 `by`s in the data array?

Comment: @David If the `by`s are formed when grouping then `count` will correspond to the number of `by`s.

Comment: @David Are you not able to get the desired output with the above aggregation?

Comment: awesome, your answer works! thanks! what does the `count: { $sum: 1 }` do in the `$group` ? it counts the number of objects in the data array?

Comment: @David I added the `$sum` reference document in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your model is called `Employee`:

```
Employee.find({ { "social_account.2": { "$exists": false }} },function(err,docs) {

})
```

As `$exists` asks for the 2 index of an array which means it has something in it.

The same applies to a maximum number:

```
Employee.find({ { "social_account.9": { "$exists": true}} },function(err,docs) {

})
```

For your perspective I think this should be your answer:

```
Employee.find({ { "data.2": { "$exists": false }} },function(err,docs) {

})
```